# Does Angular have an event for when a controller is created?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried using `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, next){...})`, but sometimes `next.scope` is undefined. Is there an event I can use once a controller's `$scope` is ready?

I have a service that I want to perform an action whenever there's a new route loaded, and I'd rather not have to add a function call at the beginning of every controller.

Comment: have u tried ng-init ?

Comment: I don't think that's applicable in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there is no documented event that a controller scope will emit when it is ready.

But what u can achieve your purpose with the following code but it is a little tricky:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(evt, to, params) {
            console.log(to.scope); // undefined
            $rootScope.$evalAsync(function(){
                console.log(to.scope); //it is ready
            })
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering, can we be sure the code in $evalAsync() will only execute after the $scope is created?

Comment: It should be, since function in $evalAsync() is executed after current angular $digest() and the creation of scope for the next controller is scheduled in digest when the $routeChangeSuccess is fired.